# Need assistance with adding text into nodes in codeflower graph via D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been trying to modify Codeflower's code in Codeflower.js (taken from here: http://www.redotheweb.com/CodeFlower/) ,for inserting text in each node (modified the update function).

The approach I took was grouping each node with text, see the concept below:

[image: The way I approached]
but after dozen of tries couldn't figure out what am I doing wrong with the code flowercode.
can somebody assist me?

Thank you all

P.S
I tried to put the code on jsfiddle,
but it didn't work well so eventually decided to post screen shot.

Comment: don't see anything wrong in the posted screen shot can you also put your code on the fiddle...even though its not wrking

Comment: the fiddle you passed is empty !

Comment: Fixed the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/Gilco333/q3f0ume5 , and here is my screen-shot taken from firebug: goo.gl/photos/ogmhVWgYGvw7qDkm6 . Can somebody explain how to fix the issue? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [screen shot](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipP-7y0BInKq6J8uQ62NwDxnXoTbXrUZJR0r3HSqnJ_zWH1hMXR9d3Lj7jyAFHDG3g?key=Z0NSSEtIMGNSU3NCUGpUV0RkbkJhemdxa0Q5ZkVB) 
The problem is about the circle tag end  your svg does not have that
Your SVG is like this

```html
<div id="viz">
    <svg width="520px" height="520px">
        <g transform="translate(260,260)">
            <circle r="54" style="fill: wheat;">
                <text>family</text>
            </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Corrected svg should be like this **note** the end tag for circle `</circle>`:

```html
<div id="viz">
    <svg width="520px" height="520px">
        <g transform="translate(260,260)">
            <circle r="54" style="fill: wheat;"></circle>
                <text>family</text>
            </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have wrote down simple js, and got the the correct result (https://goo.gl/photos/k2NAp5FkxCPPukHU7) it seams the end tag for circle was not necessary, then I tried to modify the code of CodeFlower with the same approach BUT something went totally wrong. Here is a link to the CodeFlower's modified code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gilco333/q3f0ume5/1/ . Thank you!